# Trouble inserting a quotation in the titlepage of an article

Tags: titles, quotation

I am working on a simple paper, and I would like to inser a quote on the title page. Currently, I have the following code (for the titlepage):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,cancel,amsbsy,amsfonts,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,tikz}
\input{inkscape.tex}

\title{My Title \\[.4cm] Is Here}
\date{\vspace{12cm} 18 de fevereiro, 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}                   
\maketitle                          
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\ornament{scale=1}};
\end{tikzpicture}                   

\thispagestyle{empty}               
\end{titlepage}
```

The code above produces the following output:

[image: Original Title Page]

And I would like to add a quotation to this page, preferably using `epigraph package` to get something as follows:

[image: Final Preview]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Maybe the `epigraph` package could help?

Comment: I stated in the post that I would, indeed, like to use the `epigraph` package. But when I try to, it skips to the next page (i..e, it doesn't write in the `titlepage`)

Comment: Your code is not not compilable. What's `\ornament`?  And `inkscape.tex`?

Answer (score 1):

A revised version of your MWE as it does not compile (per @Bernard), but with an epigraph added.

```
% epiprob.tex SE 634361

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,cancel,amsbsy,amsfonts,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}


\title{My Title \\[.4cm] Is Here}
\author{roro}
\date{\vspace{6cm}
%  
  \epigraph{Unforgettable words}{Peter W.}
%
  \vspace{6cm}
%
  18 de fevereiro, 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}                   
\maketitle                          

\thispagestyle{empty}               
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think, but not sure, that `titlepage` typically only typesets the `title`, `author` and `date` before going to the next page. I added the epigraph as part of the `\date` command.

Answer (score 0):

The title page is created using a `tikzpicture` with three nodes: `\maketitle` (title and date), the right corner ornament, and the epigraph.

The vertical position of the epigraph is now set by `shift={(0cm,-3cm)}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}

\newsavebox{\epigr}
\savebox{\epigr}{%
\parbox{0pt}{% quote <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\epigraph{Nenhum problema pode ser solucionado com a mesma consciência que foi criada.}{Albert Einstein}}
}

%\input{inkscape.tex} %???

\title{My Title \\[.4cm] Is Here}
\date{\vspace{12cm} 18 de fevereiro, 2022}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{titlepage}   
\parindent0pt
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[text width=\linewidth,align=center](TitleText){\maketitle} ;
    \node[anchor=north east, shift={(1cm,2cm)}](CNE)
    at (TitleText.north east){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{42}};
    \node[shift={(0cm,-3cm)},anchor=west](W) at (TitleText.west){\usebox{\epigr}};
\end{tikzpicture}         
        
\thispagestyle{empty}               
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```